# ResultSet Parser too slow

Tags: java, jdbc, time

I need to parse a huge ResultSet from a previous query and I came up with something but it is way too slow.

```
public LinkedList<CountryFirstData> sortCountryFirst() throws SQLException {

    long parsingStart = System.nanoTime();


    LinkedList<CountryFirstData> list = new LinkedList<CountryFirstData>();

    String serie;
    String unit;
    String country;
    BigDecimal value;
    int year;
    int index;

    while (rs.next()) {

        serie = rs.getString(1); // rs is the previously built resultSet
        unit = rs.getString(2);
        country = rs.getString(3);
        value = rs.getBigDecimal(4);
        year = rs.getInt(5);
        if ((index = list.indexOf(new CountryFirstData(country, serie, unit))) != -1) {

            list.get(index).getDuo().add(new YearValueDuo(year, value));

        }
        else {

            CountryFirstData data = new CountryFirstData(country, serie, unit);
            data.getDuo().add(new YearValueDuo(year, value));
            list.add(data);

        }



    }
    long parsingEnd = System.nanoTime();

    Collections.sort(list);

    long sortEnd = System.nanoTime();


    System.out.println("Parsing Time = " + ((parsingEnd - parsingStart)/1000000000)); // gives 112s
    System.out.println("Sorting Time = " + ((sortEnd - parsingEnd)/1000000000)); // gives 0s


    return list;

}
```

I will try to explain the code a bit :

The resultSet columns contain 5 different values. The first trio to consider is composed of `country`, `serie` and `unit`. When I first get such a trio (`else` case), I need to create a new `CountryFirstData` and add the remaining duo year/value from the resultSet line to the `YearValueDuo` list field in the created Object.

When the trio `country`, `serie` and `unit` already exists in the `list` (`if` case), I need to retrieve it and add the duo year/value to its `YearValueDuo` list.

So, basically, the resultSet rs is 4000 lines long and the whole parsing (sort excluded) takes 2 minutes. I feel like this is too much for only 4k lines. The sort is still fast (less than a second).

I chose a `LinkedList` for the `CountryFirstData` over an `ArrayList` because, later, I write of the whole list in its order in a file (which is really quick).

Do you guys can suggest me some improvements?

Comment: You perform a ``list.indexOf(new CountryFirstData(country, serie, unit))`` for each row. Depending on how complex ``CountryFirstData.equals`` is, this might take quite long when ``list`` has 3999 entries. try to measure the time that the ``indexOf`` method takes for each row.

Comment: @f1sh Will do, ty. I haven't found a better way yet to test if the specified `CountryFirstData` already exists in the list.

Comment: Comparing (in list) one instance of object, adding the other seems ugly.

Comment: @JacekCz no, that looks fine. What's ugly about the code?

Comment: @f1sh One times creation `new CountryFirstData` before `if` would be better

Comment: @JacekCz Oh, I understand you. I don't really care about cuteness but about efficiency. And your proposal seems more efficient even if we more often enter the `if` case, right?

Comment: @Fitz Yes, but more important is error risk when algorithm will grow in the future.

Comment: Did You check with debugger, maybe "else" is executed always? How is implemented CountryFirstData.eqauals

Comment: @JacekCz No, I didn't, I will. But it is as if I checked since the output looks as intended and wouldn't if `else` was always executed (meaning there would be 4000 different `CountryFirstData` with only one `YearValueDuo` in each). [Here](http://pastebin.com/Gn95C0Gu) is my `CountryFirstData.equals`

Comment: @JacekCz I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand your last reply. What do you mean by "grow in the future"?

Comment: @f1sh I changed my code to [this](http://pastebin.com/GKEj72zT) to test the time taken by `list.indexOf(new CountryFirstData(cou‌​‌​ntry, serie, unit))`. It gives less than a second in total. But I am not confident in my way of measuring time

Comment: which database are you running this against?

Comment: Use a `HashSet` instead of a `List`. If you're not confident about your measurements there is no question here to answer.

Comment: @EJP I provided thru links the code I am using to measure the time. So, a quick look by someone with more knowlegde should confirme (or not) the way I measured.

Comment: @Palcente Oracle Database.

Comment: @Fitz is your fetch size set to default ? If positive, try setting it to 5000 and  check if that made any difference...

Comment: @EJP  A `HashShet` for the `CountryFirstData` List I guess. I'll try, ty!

Comment: @Palcente It is default. I'll set it to 5000 to try!

Comment: @Fitz that means it was hitting database 400 times to get your 4000 records... it's most likely the cause of your troubles

Comment: @Palcente I added `rs.setFetchSize(5000);` before the `while (rs.next()) {` and it seems like I won 5 seconds (from 112 to 107).

Comment: @EJP A `HashSet` can not work if just replacing since it doesn't have any `retreive` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A List, and that actually a Set (no doubles), and afterwards sorted. And returning the implementing class, forcing further usage to use that type, preventing implementation change.

```
public Set<CountryFirstData> sortCountryFirst() throws SQLException {

    long parsingStart = System.nanoTime();

    SortedMap<CountryFirstData, CountryFirstData> identityMap = new TreeMap<>();
    //      Comparator.comparing(CountryFirstData::getCountry)
    //          .thenComparing(CountryFirstData::getSerie))
    //          .thenComparing(CountryFirstData::getUnit));

    while (rs.next()) {

        String serie = rs.getString(1); // rs is the previously built resultSet
        String unit = rs.getString(2);
        Stribg country = rs.getString(3);
        BigDecimal value = rs.getBigDecimal(4);
        int year = rs.getInt(5);
        CountryFirstData data = new CountryFirstData(country, serie, unit));
        CountryFirstData oldData = identityMap.putIfAbsent(data, data);
        if (oldData != null) {
            data = oldData;
        }
        data.getDuo().add(new YearValueDuo(year, value));
    }
    long parsingEnd = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("Parsing Time = " + ((parsingEnd - parsingStart)/1_000_000_000L));

    return (SortedSet<CountryFi‌​rstData>) identityMap.keySet()‌​;
}
```

This relies on the already existing compare *and* on the equals.

The trick here is - that though you just need a Set -, an identity map is needed to fetch the old equal value '(`Set.add` only returns a boolean).

---

***As this is still to slow:***

Ensure that the ResultSet is already sorted by SQL `ORDER BY serie, unit, country`. (If already sorted, that would explain slowness in the prior solution: a tree map, that becomes a linear list.)

```
public List<CountryFirstData> sortCountryFirst() throws SQLException {

    long parsingStart = System.nanoTime();

    List<CountryFirstData> identityMap = new ArrayList<>();
    CountryFirstData oldData = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String serie = rs.getString(1); // rs is the previously built resultSet
        String unit = rs.getString(2);
        Stribg country = rs.getString(3);
        BigDecimal value = rs.getBigDecimal(4);
        int year = rs.getInt(5);
        CountryFirstData data = new CountryFirstData(country, serie, unit));
        if (oldData == null || data.compareTo(oldData) != 0) {
            oldData = data;
            list.add(data);
        }
        oldData.getDuo().add(new YearValueDuo(year, value));
    }
    long parsingEnd = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("Parsing Time = " + ((parsingEnd - parsingStart)/1_000_000_000L));

    return list;
}
```

This leaves the hard work to the database. What is fastest and can exploit indices.

Comment: I guess you meant by `return list.keySet();` actually `return identityMap.keySet();`? Ty, I'll try right now.

Comment: Won me 5 seconds. Better than nothing, thank you! Had to cast just saying : `return (SortedSet<CountryFirstData>) identityMap.keySet();`

Comment: I have added a very fast solution, but it requires the SQL to be changed.

Comment: I can change the SQL so, I will try it but the ResultSet wasn't sorted as I tested the query in SQLDevelopper.

Comment: Results : total time : 115s with 114s for the query only. I guess this is the best we can hope for. Means, my previous code wasn't that bad, I guess.

Comment: The database is guilty. Indexes. Or more heap space java -Xmx 2G